# Failing to parse json after sending an ajax request

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, api, parsing

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#redeem_token').click(function() {
        var username = $('#username').val(); ///* input id=username field *//
        var password = $('#password').val(); ///* input id=password field *//
        var password2 = $('#password2').val();  ///* input id=password2 field *//       
        var dataString = '{"username":"'+username+'","password":"'+password+'","password2":"'+password2+'"}';
        
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "api/auth/register.php",
            data: dataString,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(json) {
   console.log(JSON.stringify(json.main));
   $.each(json.main, function(idx, messages){
    $("#redeem").html('' + messages.status + "");
                       });
            }
        });
        
        return false;
    });
});
```

Response example:

```
{"main":{"messages":{"status":"Success","message":"Registration successful!"}}}
```

I dont know what am i doing wrong, nothing is showing up in my *id=redeem* Html field.
I've searched everywhere still not found.

Comment: Is the `JSON.stringify(json.main)` logging?

Comment: Are you sure that the `json` object returned from the API is an object? Could it be a string that needs parsed before you can inspect `json.main`?

Comment: Well, i have no idea what does that code do, i took this `JSON.stringify(json.main)` from another stackoverflow topic but its still not working for me after hours of attempts, i tried many things so far

Comment: try JSON.stringify(dataString)

Comment: Try to `console.log(json)` see if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New Code: i wrote   `$("#redeem").html(' '+messages.message+' ');` instead of     `$("#redeem").html('' + messages.status + "");`
its working perfect now